# recreating shadows

Tags: lighting, shadows, photorealism

How could I recreate this enviroment with these soft shadows? and how to make it more realistic?

Example with good realistic shadows:

[image]

My example
[image]

Comment: maybe give your wall a Noise Texture with a b&w ColorRamp, but it looks like you're already close to your example. As for the shadow it looks like there are 2 light sources in your picture

Comment: You don't need to re-create the shadows, that might turn out to be pretty tedious. Just create them, using proper lighting. The latter is an art form and not as simple as it might seem, but it's worth at least understanding the concept (by following tutorials, or reading up on the fundamentals).